# How can I calculate the summation of numerical value of a repetitive header individually in a single column of a csv file?

Tags: python

```
Atom    Energy
P   0.915850909
S   0.139015529
O   0.287955449
N   0.081249517
Atom    Energy
C   0.366759452
H   0.712749905
P   0.041385313
S   0.212815601
Atom    Energy
C   0.118311183
H   0.459529329
N   0.786848406
S   0.835356163
```

I want to calculate the summation of the "Energy" individually present in a column by using python programming.

Comment: some code, please. In which file format are stored the data? Which library? ....numpy?

Comment: What have you tried? Please include some code.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that the amount of rows containing numerical values stays constant, the "chunk size".

```
n = text.count('Atom')
N = 4 # chunk size

data = [float(s.split(' ')[-1]) for s in text.split('\n') if s[-1].isdigit()]

for i in range(n):
    print(sum(data[i*N:(i+1)*N]))
```

Output

```
1.424071404
1.333710271
2.200045081
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question. When the chuk size is not fixed, then what will be the code in python?

Comment: @Ashis Nandy If my solution answer your question mark it!

Answer (score 0):

For the case of non-fixed number of rows

```
text = """Atom    Energy
P   0.915850909
S   0.139015529
O   0.287955449
N   0.081249517
Atom    Energy
C   0.366759452
H   0.712749905
P   0.041385313
Q   1.01385313
S   0.212815601
Atom    Energy
C   0.118311183
H   0.459529329
N   0.786848406
S   0.835356163
V   10.83535616
"""

groups = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.replace('  ', ' ')  # replace multiple space by 1 single, generate list with an ' '-entry
    c_label, c_ws, c_float = line.split(' ') 
    if c_label == 'Atom':
        groups += [[]]
    else:
        groups[-1] += [float(c_float)]

grouped_sum = [sum(v) for v in groups]

print(grouped_sum)
```